# Why are there different sections for initialized and uninitialized globals?

Tags: language-agnostic, executable

I'm reading this course on the structure of an executable and it says there are three data sections in an executable:

- **code section** — where the instructions are stored
- **data section**

  - *.data* — stores initialized global data
  - *.bss* — stores uninitialized global data
  - *.rodata* — stores read-only data, such as literals

My question is, why is the distinction made between initialized and uninitialized global data?

(We use C in class, but I guess this is a language agnostic subject.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image size.  The program image has to contain the initialization data for .data, but it does not have to contain .bss.